# Are there any Christian characters in LOST who aren't Catholic?

Tags: religion, lost, christian

Because, in fiction, [Christianity is Catholic](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ChristianityIsCatholic) ([TV Tropes Warning!](https://youtu.be/c6waxdDmGqs)), the vast majority of *LOST* characters who are Christian, are nominally Christian or used to be Christian are or were Catholic.

Including but not limited to:

- Mr. Eko and Yemi (who were both Catholic priests)
- Charlie
- Kate (at least in her past)
- Desmond (who was a Novice at a monastery)
- Claire (nominally)
- Christian (At least nominally)
- The Reyes family
- Richard and Isabella

As well as various other minor characters.

Are there any Christian characters shown who explicitly or are highly implied to belong to a different denomination?

Comment: http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Christianity - "*A single explicit reference to Protestantism was made by revealing Francis Heatherton's earlier involvement in a rock band called "The Protestant Reformation."*